# I'm seeing stars

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

While composing [this recent answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/406526/163930) I ran across a funny effect of markdown rendering. I wanted to put a quote in bold and italic, and the simplest way for me is to put three asterisks before and after the quote

> `***"Get 'er done!"***`

which renders as

> ***"Get 'er Done!"***

But I accidentally put ***four*** asterisks at the beginning, and this turned off all rendering:

> ****"Get 'er Done!"***

I would have expected to see

> ****"Get 'er Done!"***

My first guess was that the markdown engine was parsing all of the special characters as one token, but my last example invalidated that.

Is this correct behavior?

Answer (score 13):

This is by design.

> a sequence of more than three underscores or more than three asterisks will no longer take part in any emphasis.

Source: [balpha the Markdown wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240354).